# How condition(==) check works in JAVA?

Tags: java

can someone explains how this line works in JAVA?

```
boolean result = value == null
```

Comment: The key is operator precedence (between `=` and `==`). [Here's the documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It evaluates `value == null`, and assigns true or false to `result`.

Due to the evaluation order, you don't need parentheses `result = (value == null)`.

Comment: Some style guides (for example, [Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.7-grouping-parentheses)) recommend that the redundant parentheses are included anyway for readability, and for the benefit of those who haven't committed the order of precedence to memory.

Comment: @jsheeran good point - I am a big fan of coding styles, but I think Google had things in mind like this: `boolean result = !Stream.of(((Function<Integer, Integer>) (x) -> 2).apply(2)).anyMatch((x) -> x.equals(2))` - although no one should ever do things like this. I think any programmer should be able to understand `result = value == null` without a second look.

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean result = value == null
```

means you declare a boolean variable `result` and assigning it to the return value of `value == null`

Answer (score 1):

1. `value == null` --> ture or false
2. boolean result = true|false

Answer (score 0):

Java will compare the value with null first, after matching both the values then resulting value will be assign as true or false to the result variable. it will check also for data type(if needed, like you cant compare boolean values with null).